# Migrating jboss to jboss-ejb3

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I have to run a JavaEE application under JBoss 6. 
I create a file jboss-ejb3.xml 
When i run the server (via standalone.bat), i have this error : 
**Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[9,5]
Message: Unexpected element '{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee}webservices' encountered
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement**

But i do not see what is wrong in my jboss-ejb3.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:c="urn:clustering:1.0"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
               version="3.1"
               impl-version="2.0">
    <webservices>
        <context-root>atom-ws</context-root>
    </webservices>
    <jboss:enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>...</ejb-name>
            <jndi-name>...</jndi-name>
            <ejb-local-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>...</ejb-ref-name>
                <local-jndi-name>...</local-jndi-name>
            </ejb-local-ref>
         </session>      
         ...
    </jboss:enterprise-beans>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

I do not see what is wrong in the structure of my jboss-ejb3.xml 
The webservice and jboss:enterprise-beans elements are copied  from the jboss.xml under the version 5 of JBoss.

Please, can you say me if you see a problem in the structure of the jboss-ejb3.xml file. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following to jboss-web.xml

```
<webservices>
        <context-root>atom-ws</context-root>
    </webservices>
```

use both jboss-web.xml and jboss-ejb3.xml

Comment: Thanks Sharique. In fact, i let my previous jboss (from jboss 5) and it works always under jboss 6. Thank you Sharique for your tip.